# How to subset data frame by date and perform multiple operations in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I receive daily CSV reports, and each has the same number of variables but from different times. I want to run some simple analysis based on date and save the results. I think a `for` loop can do the job, but I only know the basics. Ideally, I only need to run the script once a month and get the results. Any guidance or advise is appreciated.

Let's say I have two CSV reports in a folder:

```
#File 1 - 20200624.csv
Date        Market  Salesman    Product Quantity    Price   Cost
6/24/2020   A       MF          Apple   20          1       0.5
6/24/2020   A       RP          Apple   15          1       0.5
6/24/2020   A       RP          Banana  20          2       0.5
6/24/2020   A       FR          Orange  20          3       0.5
6/24/2020   B       MF          Apple   20          1       0.5
6/24/2020   B       RP          Banana  20          2       0.5

#File 2 - 20200625.csv
Date        Market  Salesman    Product Quantity    Price   Cost
6/25/2020   A       MF          Apple   10          1       0.6
6/25/2020   A       MF          Banana  15          1       0.6
6/25/2020   A       RP          Banana  10          2       0.6
6/25/2020   A       FR          Orange  15          3       0.6
6/25/2020   B       MF          Apple   20          1       0.6
6/25/2020   B       RP          Banana  20          2       0.6
```

I imported all the files into R using the following codes:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

#Import files
files <- list.files(path = "~/JuneReports", 
                    pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)
tbl <- sapply(files, read_csv, simplify=FALSE) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "id")
#Remove the "id" column
tbl2 <- tbl[,-1]
#Subset the data frame to get only Mark A, as Market B is irrelavant.
tbl3 <- subset(tbl2, Market == "A")
head(tbl3)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Date      Market Salesman Product Quantity Price  Cost
  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 6/24/2020 A      MF       Apple         20     1   0.5
2 6/24/2020 A      RP       Apple         15     1   0.5
3 6/24/2020 A      RP       Banana        20     2   0.5
4 6/24/2020 A      FR       Orange        20     3   0.5
5 6/25/2020 A      MF       Apple         10     1   0.6
6 6/25/2020 A      MF       Banana        15     1   0.6
```

Below are the results I want to get:

```
Date        Market  Revenue Total Cost  Apples Sold Bananas Sold    Oranges Sold
6/24/2020   A       135     37.5        35          20              20
6/25/2020   A       90      30          15          25              15

#Revenue = sumproduct(Quantity, Price)
#Total Cost = sumproduct(Quantity, Cost)
#Apples/Bananas/Oranges Sold = sum(Product == "Apple/Banana/Orange")
```

Comment: You may use `%*%`

Comment: @akrun Could you please provide more details?

Comment: My solution output is based on the `head` data you showed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group by 'Date', 'Market', calculate the sum of product of 'Quantity' with 'Price', and 'Cost', `.add` that also in the `group_by` along with 'Product', get the `sum` of 'Quantity' and use `pivot_wider` to reshape into 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Date, Market) %>% 
    group_by(Revenue = c(Quantity %*% Price), 
             TotalCost = c(Quantity %*% Cost),
             Product, .add = TRUE) %>% 
    summarise(Sold = sum(Quantity)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Product, values_from = Sold)
# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Groups:   Date, Market, Revenue, TotalCost [2]
#  Date      Market Revenue TotalCost Apple Banana Orange
#  <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl> <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 6/24/2020 A          135      37.5    35     20     20
#2 6/25/2020 A           25      15      10     15     NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("6/24/2020", "6/24/2020", "6/24/2020", 
"6/24/2020", "6/25/2020", "6/25/2020"), Market = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A"), Salesman = c("MF", "RP", "RP", "FR", "MF", 
"MF"), Product = c("Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple", 
"Banana"), Quantity = c(20L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 15L), Price = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), Cost = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: awesome! But, I think you want `add = TRUE` not `.add = TRUE`

Comment: @KJM IN `dplyr 1.0.0` `group_by(.data, ..., .add = FALSE, .drop = group_by_drop_default(.data))`

Comment: My bad! Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @KJM with each releasse, there are some changes.  I agree that it makes it out of place when you are working on a different version.  Sorry, I forgot to mention the version

Comment: We'll just have to get used to it I guess, I'm going to update my `tidyverse` packages to be on top of it. Another question, I tried this code having just one `group_by()` (i.e. `group_by(Date, Market, Revenue = c(Quantity %*% Price), TotalCost = c(Quantity %*% Cost), Product)`) but it doesn't work. Do we `group_by()` twice as we are effectively grouping each group?

Comment: @KJM It may not work because the Quantity %*% Price should be within Date and Market.  The code you used would do the calculation on the entire column

Comment: Yes that makes sense, and finally (sorry for so many questions but I love tidyverse and really want to understand it) why do you use `%*%`? Your code also works with `Revenue = sum(Quantity * Price), TotalCost = sum(Quantity * Cost)`. Is using `Revenue = c(Quantity %*% Price), TotalCost = c(Quantity %*% Cost)` better? I can ask this as a separate SO question if you'd like.

Comment: @KJM Yes, you can do that.  I commented `%*%` and the OP asked how, so I used it.  You can post it. thanks

Comment: Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62603566/difference-between-c-and-sum

Comment: @akrun Beautiful! A follow-up question - how can I add three more columns to the existing result showing the quantity sold by salesmen? I added   `group_by(Revenue = c(Quantity %*% Price),TotalCost = c(Quantity %*% Cost),Salesman, .add = TRUE)` and `pivot_wider(names_from = Salesman, values_from = Sold)`, but got `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.`

Comment: @T-T do you need `df1 %>%
+     group_by(Date, Market) %>% 
+     group_by(Revenue = c(Quantity %*% Price), 
+              TotalCost = c(Quantity %*% Cost),
+              Product, Salesman, .add = TRUE) %>%   summarise(Sold = sum(Quantity)) %>% 
+     pivot_wider(names_from = Product, values_from = Sold)`

Comment: @akrun Yes, I need that plus three more columns for quantity sold by salesmen. The example is simplified. The actual case requires calculations on different groups. So I'm trying to learn as much as I can from your answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: @T-T if it is a completely different case, can you post as a new question. thanks

Comment: @akrun here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62603956/how-to-add-additional-columns-using-tidyr-group-by-function-in-r. Please take a look.