# Difference between c(... %*% ...) and sum(... * ...)

Tags: r, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

This question is a follow up to the discussion from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602978/how-to-subset-data-frame-by-date-and-perform-multiple-operations-in-r/62603120#62603120) answer.

What is the difference between using `c(... %*% ...)` and `sum(... * ...)` in a `group_by()` function from `dplyr`?

Both of these code give the same result:

**#1**

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Date, Market) %>% 
    group_by(Revenue = c(Quantity %*% Price), 
             TotalCost = c(Quantity %*% Cost),
             Product, .add = TRUE) %>% 
    summarise(Sold = sum(Quantity)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Product, values_from = Sold)
```

**#2**

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Date, Market) %>% 
    group_by(Revenue = sum(Quantity * Price), 
             TotalCost = sum(Quantity * Cost),
             Product, .add = TRUE) %>% 
    summarise(Sold = sum(Quantity)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Product, values_from = Sold)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Groups:   Date, Market, Revenue, TotalCost [2]
#  Date      Market Revenue TotalCost Apple Banana Orange
#  <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl> <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 6/24/2020 A          135      37.5    35     20     20
#2 6/25/2020 A           25      15      10     15     NA
```

Is one of `c(... %*% ...)` and `sum(... * ...)` better/quicker/preferred/neater?

---

The **DATA** in the original answer:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("6/24/2020", "6/24/2020", "6/24/2020", 
"6/24/2020", "6/25/2020", "6/25/2020"), Market = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A"), Salesman = c("MF", "RP", "RP", "FR", "MF", 
"MF"), Product = c("Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple", 
"Banana"), Quantity = c(20L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 15L), Price = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), Cost = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: You could use `microbenchmark` or `system.time` on a bigger dataset

Comment: But functionally how are they different? What are the individual steps going on in each case 'in the background'?

Comment: `%*%` is the matrix product. Does that help?

Comment: @HongOoi, yes that does help, although I'll have to read up specifically how matrix multiplication works. Am I right in saying that that using `*` on two vectors multiplies each element in one vector by the corresponding element in another vector, and if one is shorter than the other then its elements are recycled in a `rep(<shorter_vector>, lenght.out = length(<longer_vector>))` fashion? Maybe in a case where the vectors are of unequal  lengths, using `sum(<longer_vector> * <shorter_vector>)`  is better as `c(<longer_vector> %*% <shorter_vector>)` throws an error (non-conformable arguments).

Comment: There are different expectations of the two operators. You are correct that `*` does element-wise multiplication. Alternatively `%*%` does linear-algebra matrix multiplication, which is completely different. There should be no differentiation between length of vectors with the latter, because (1) they should be matrices, and (2) if there is any expectation that you might have recycling, you should not be thinking LA matrix multiplication, since that can *only* happen if the two matrices have perfectly-compatible dimensions (`ncol(m1) == nrow(m2)`).

Comment: Said differently ... be clear with what you are using. If `Quantity` and `Price` are both vectors, and `Quantity * Price` makes *sense* to you, then use `*`. To me, that is all that is important. If there is any doubt as to what you are getting, compare `1:4 * 2:5` (length 4) with `1:4 %*% 2:5` (length 1). What is logically what you need?

Comment: Thank you @r2evans, that is really clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll compile the comments into an answer, others can jump in if I miss anything.

- `%*%` and `*` are drastically different operators: `*` does element-wise multiplication, and `%*%` does linear algebra matrix multiplication. Those are very different operations, demonstrated with:

  ```r
  1:4 * 2:5
  # [1]  2  6 12 20

  1:4 %*% 2:5
  #      [,1]
  # [1,]   40

  sum(1:4 * 2:5)
  # [1] 40
  ```

  If you are looking for a single summary statistic from multiply two vectors, and the matrix-multiply from linear algebra makes sense, then `%*%` is the right tool for you.
- there should be something said about *declarative* code; while you can do the third operation (`sum(.*.)`), to me it may be better to use `%*%`, for two reasons:

  1. Declarative intent. I am saying that I have two matrices that I intend to do "linear algebra" on.
  2. Safeguards. If there is any dimensional mismatch (e.g., `sum(1:4 * 2:3)` still works syntactically but `1:4 %*% 2:3` does not), I want to know it right away. With `sum(.*.)`, the mismatch is silently ignored to the world (one reason I think recycling can be a big problem).
  3. The reason is *not* performance: while with smaller vectors/matrices `%*%`'s performance is on par with `sum(.*.)`, as the size of the data gets larger, `%*%` is relatively more expensive.

     ```r
     m1 <- 1:100 ; m2 <- m1+1 ; m3 <- 1:100000; m4 <- m3+1
     microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sm1 = sum(m1*m2), sm2 = m1%*%m2, lg1 = sum(m3*m4), lg2 = m3%*%m4)
     # Unit: nanoseconds
     #  expr    min     lq   mean median     uq      max neval
     #   sm1    800   1100 112900   1600   2100 11083600   100
     #   sm2   1100   1400   2143   1900   2450    10200   100
     #   lg1 239700 249550 411235 270800 355300 11102800   100
     #   lg2 547900 575550 634763 637850 678250   780500   100
     ```
- All of the discussion so far has been on *vectors*, which are effectively 1d matrices (as far as `%*%` seems to think ... though even that is not fully accurate). Once you start getting into true matrices, it becomes more difficult to interchange them ... in fact, I don't know of an easier way to emulate `%*%` (short of `for` loops, etc):

  ```r
  m1 %*% m2
  #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  # [1,]   22   49   76  103
  # [2,]   28   64  100  136
  t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(m1)), function(i) sapply(seq_len(ncol(m2)), function(j) sum(m1[i,] * m2[,j]))))
  #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  # [1,]   22   49   76  103
  # [2,]   28   64  100  136
  ```

  (And while that nested-`sapply` may not be the fastest non-`%*%` way to do the matrix-y stuff, `%*%` is 1-2 orders of magnitude *faster*, since it is `.Internal` and compiled and *meant* for **"Math!"** like this.)

Bottom line, while `%*%` does *use* the `*` operator internally (for one of a couple steps), the two are otherwise different. Heck, one might also compare `*` and `^` in the same vein ... with a similar outcome.

Cheers!

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the in-depth answer and pointing out essentially just a superficial similarity in output between `sum(.*.)` and `%*%`.