# How to add additional columns using tidyr group_by function in R?

Tags: r, tidyr

This question is a follow up to my post from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602978/how-to-subset-data-frame-by-date-and-perform-multiple-operations-in-r/62603120?noredirect=1#comment110710318_62603120) answer.

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("6/24/2020", "6/24/2020", "6/24/2020", 
"6/24/2020", "6/25/2020", "6/25/2020"), Market = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A"), Salesman = c("MF", "RP", "RP", "FR", "MF", 
"MF"), Product = c("Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple", 
"Banana"), Quantity = c(20L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 15L), Price = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), Cost = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

**Solution**

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Date, Market) %>% 
    group_by(Revenue = c(Quantity %*% Price), 
             TotalCost = c(Quantity %*% Cost),
             Product, .add = TRUE) %>% 
    summarise(Sold = sum(Quantity)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Product, values_from = Sold)
# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Groups:   Date, Market, Revenue, TotalCost [2]
#  Date      Market Revenue TotalCost Apple Banana Orange
#  <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl> <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 6/24/2020 A          135      37.5    35     20     20
#2 6/25/2020 A           25      15      10     15     NA
```

@akrun's solution works well. Now I'd like to know how to add three more columns for quantity sold by salesmen to the existing results so the final output will look like this:

```
Date        Market  Revenue Total Cost  Apples Sold Bananas Sold    Oranges Sold    MF  RP  FR
6/24/2020   A       135     37.5        35          20              20              20  35  20
6/25/2020   A       25      15          15          25              NA              25  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to do the group by operations separately as these are done on separate columns and then do a join by the common columns i.e. 'Date', 'Market'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out1 <- df1 %>%
           group_by(Date, Market) %>% 
           group_by(Revenue = c(Quantity %*% Price), 
                    TotalCost = c(Quantity %*% Cost),
                     Product, .add = TRUE) %>% 
          summarise(Sold = sum(Quantity)) %>% 
          pivot_wider(names_from = Product, values_from = Sold)
out2 <- df1 %>% 
          group_by(Date, Market, Salesman) %>% 
          summarise(SalesSold = sum(Quantity)) %>% 
          pivot_wider(names_from = Salesman, values_from = SalesSold)

left_join(out1, out2)
# A tibble: 2 x 10
# Groups:   Date, Market, Revenue, TotalCost [2]
#  Date      Market Revenue TotalCost Apple Banana Orange    FR    MF    RP
#  <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl> <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 6/24/2020 A          135      37.5    35     20     20    20    20    35
#2 6/25/2020 A           25      15      10     15     NA    NA    25    NA
```